# How to make button text change on-click then change back after 2 seconds?

Tags: jquery

I have this code for making button text change on clicking to different text. It works. However, what I need now is to make the new text get back to the original text after 2 seconds.

Here is the code that partially works:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#shahadas").click(function() {
    $(this).text(function(i, v) {
      return v === 'Did 100 Push Ups!' ? '1,000 Coins Awarded!' : 'Did 100 Push Ups!'
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

I'm expecting that someone helps me with the final code to use.

Comment: use `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#shahadas', function(){
  const t = $(this);
  if( t.hasClass('active') ){
    return;
  }
  t.addClass('active');
  t.data('text', t.text());
  t.text( t.data('text-active') );
  setTimeout(() => {
    t.text( t.data('text') );
    t.removeClass('active');
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="shahadas" data-text-active="Did 100 Push Ups!">Click Me</button>
```